# Accidentally misconfigured T type thermocouples as J. How do I convert my data?

Tags: thermocouple

I was running a test between -70C and 70C using T type thermocouples but misconfigured it on my DAQ(keysight) to J. Is there a way to convert the data I gathered to the correct settings?

Comment: yes divide by T sensitivity and multiply by J

Comment: As Tony says: Applying the inverse of the table or function that converted the "T" readings from voltage to temperature will give you the original voltage readings - or thermocouple resistances. Now convert that with the correct table or function / algorithm.

Comment: can you do this?

Comment: if not say so.. gain correction is roughly x1.1852 using a spreadsheet

Comment: After you correct the J setting, repeat the test - best way to be sure and have correct primary data.

Comment: @mugetsu  What kind of formula (or table, or algorithm) was [mis]used when you have [originally] misconfigured the thermocouple?